# Android - Adding separate components to Activity once setContentView is used

Tags: android, view

I have created an external class, NotesView, which extends View for implementation in my MainActivity.

This View requires information passed from the MainActivity, so its constructor takes an ArrayList of Note objects.

```
public class NotesView extends View {

private ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

public NotesView(Context context, ArrayList<Note> notes) {
    super(context);
    this.notes = notes;
}
```

In my MainActivity, I used the following code to display this view: (Trying to add a CustomView in the Design tab of the layout does not work as I cannot supply the ArrayList parameter)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notesView = new NotesView(this, noteList);
    setContentView(notesView);
}
```

Unfortunately, I am now not able to add any objects at all through the Design view of the layout, I assume this is because I have used setContentView. I do not wish to add all my components programmatically, is there a way around this?

Comment: Why don't you use Recyclerview / Listview. Seems to match perfect for your use case

Comment: See [Android: Passing an arbitrary object to a custom View](http://curioustechizen.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-passing-arbitrary-object-to.html) probably help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `setContentView` replaces the whole view for your layout. That means if you call `setContentView` twice, whatever was added to the screen from the first call is overridden and no longer accessible.

---

There are multiple answers to your question, here is a pragmatic one:

What is inside `R.layout.activity_main`? Let's assume there is a `FrameLayout` / `LinearLayout` / `RelativeLayout` with id `root`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
    notesView = new NotesView(this, noteList);
    rootView.addView(notesView);
}
```

---

Another choice, you could also take your custom view to have a setter if you wish:

```
public class NotesView extends View {

private final List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

public NotesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void replaceNotes(List<Note> notes) {
   this.notes.clear();
   this.notes.addAll(notes); 
}
```

Then you can add this view in your XML file (`R.layout.activity_main`) and call the setter method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    NotesView notesView = (NotesView) findViewById(R.id.notes);
    notesView.replaceNotes(noteList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a setter function to your NotesView class:

```
public class NotesView extends View {

    private ArrayList<Note> notes;

    public NotesView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setNotes(ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```

And then set it in the main activity:

```
NotesView notesView = (NotesView) findViewById(R.id.yourNotesView);
notesView.setNotes(noteList);
```

By the way I recommend [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to cast views in your layout without the verbose findViewByIds, declarations, onXListeners, etc.